# Draw chart with different color positive and negative values in achartengine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am trying to create a line/area chart using achart library, my usecase is to show the chart as green above the predefined point and show the chart as red below the predefined point.

Please help. Please refer the sample chart

[image: Sample chart for reference]

Comment: Can you show some snap what u want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate series, one to display the line above zero and the second one for the one below.